# Process.Arguments многопоточность

Tags: c#

Как сделать чтобы `process.Arguments` запускался для каждого `label` свой?

```
con.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var i = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    var cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Подробнее", ToolStrip);
    cm.MenuItems.Add("Подключиться", StartProc);
     var _label = new Label();
    _label.Text = reader["Name_PC"].ToString();
    _label.Location = new Point(20, 25*(i++));
    _label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

    _label.Click += delegate
    {
        _label.ContextMenu = cm;
    };
    Controls.Add(_label);
    process.Arguments = _label.Text;
```

Так работает только по последнему полученному аргументу т.е 1 аргумент получил предыдущий забыл. Как исправить?

Comment: Создавайте в while каждый раз новый процесс.

Comment: Старайтесь приводить пример полностью. Желательно, что бы в нем было видно, где и какие переменные объявлены. Например, где у Вас объявлена переменная `process`?

Comment: Надеюсь, этот пример чисто учебный, и вы понимаете, почему чтение из базы данных в UI-потоке означает подвисание приложения.

Answer (score 1):

нашёл решение. Просто нужно было перенести

```
process.Arguments = _label.Text;
```

в

```
 _label.Click += delegate
         {
          _label.ContextMenu = cm;
          process.Arguments = _label.Text;
         };
```

и всё заработало как нужно